# How to create Feyman Diagrams with feynmp?

Tags: feynman, feynmp

I'm never used this package and I dont know how to use it to draw the diagramas.

Tried to draw some examples I found, but they dont even apear on my pdf file.

I saw on other forums that I had to run a  mpost file, but I dont know where I can find or how to run this file.
Here are my attemps:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{feynmp}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}

% macro to compile Feynman graphs without extra scripts
\DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{
    \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J end.^^J endinput;}
    \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
    \fi
    %\ifnum\pdfshellescape=\@ne
    \ifnum\pdfshellescape>\z@
    \immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering
        \begin{fmffile}{attemp 1}
            \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
                \fmfleft{i1}%%determina o termos da esquerda
                \fmfright{o2} %% determina o termo da direita
                \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}%%  um e- que vem da esquerda
                \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}%% um e- que vai pra direita
                \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}%% foton vai do vértice 1 para o 2
                \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o2} %fermion vem do termo i1, da esquerda, entra no vertice v1, vai de v1 para v2, e de v2 para o termo o2.
                \fmf{photon}{v1,o1} %% foton vem do vértice de baixo pra direita, o2
            \end{fmfgraph*}
        \end{fmffile}
        \vspace{5mm}
        \caption{Feynman diagram for Compton scattering} %\label{compton}
    \end{figure}
    
    \large
    \begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,60)
            \fmfleft{i1,i2}
            \fmfright{o1,o2}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
            \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
            \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
            \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
    
    \newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
        \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
            expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
            label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
            enddef;}
        \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
    
    \begin{fmffile}{diagram with arrows}
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,60)
            \fmfleft{i1,i2}
            \fmfright{o1,o2}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
            \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
            \marrow{ea}{ up }{top}{$p_1$}{i2,v2}
            \marrow{eb}{down}{bot}{$p_3$}{v2,o2}
            \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
            \marrow{ma}{down}{bot}{$p_2$}{i1,v1}
            \marrow{mb}{ up }{top}{$p_4$}{v1,o1}
            \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v1}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me for my delay but I have only cleaned your code and fixed it better because there are man eRrORS. It very difficult for me explained step by steps my improvements.

Here my MWE that works:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
        \vspace{10mm}
        \centering
        \begin{fmffile}{zxc}
            \begin{fmfgraph*}(150,100)
                \fmfleft{i1}%%determina o termos da esquerda
                \fmfright{o2} %% determina o termo da direita
                \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}%%  um e- que vem da esquerda
                \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}%% um e- que vai pra direita
                \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}%% foton vai do vértice 1 para o 2
                \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o2} %fermion vem do termo i1, da esquerda, entra no vertice v1, vai de v1 para v2, e de v2 para o termo o.
                \fmf{photon}{v1,o1} %% foton vem do vértice de baixo pra direita, o2
            \end{fmfgraph*}
        \end{fmffile}
        \vspace{5mm}
        \caption{Feynman diagram for Compton scattering} %\label{compton}
    \end{figure}
    \large
    \[\begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,60)
            \fmfleft{i1,i2}
            \fmfright{o1,o2}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
            \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
            \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
            \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}\qquad 
        \newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
        \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
            expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
            label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
            enddef;}
        \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
        \begin{fmffile}{dgs}
        \begin{fmfgraph*}(110,60)
            \fmfleft{i1,i2}
            \fmfright{o1,o2}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
            \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o2}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i1}
            \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o1}
            \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
            \marrow{ea}{ up }{top}{$p_1$}{i2,v2}
            \marrow{eb}{down}{bot}{$p_3$}{v2,o2}
            \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
            \marrow{ma}{down}{bot}{$p_2$}{i1,v1}
            \marrow{mb}{ up }{top}{$p_4$}{v1,o1}
            \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v2,v1}
        \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I compiled your code and yet the diagrams dont appear on my pdf. I dont know what i am missing. I compiled twice, following the recomendations of other foruns, and nothing happened.

Comment: @GabrielVian I don't know the causes. It may be that you haven't updated your LaTeX distribution. I don't know what you are using either TeXLive or >MikTeX. Please keep me informed.

Comment: Iam using MikTex and keeping it updated. Could this problem have any relation with that  "mpost file" I mentioned?

Comment: @GabrielVian Have you some mistakes? Can you use https://www.papeeria.com/ to compile it?

Comment: I compiled it on papeeria.com, and it worked. Thats weird, might be something with my compilator.